# Python remove string (multiple lines) in multiple files with regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking for a python script that removes a certain string (on multiple lines) and in multiple files (amount of files is not known, but they are all in the same folder)

Let's say there are 2 files in this location:

'D:\test\test'
Called XML_1.xml and XML_2.xml (if there are more files, the number just increases)

All files follow this structure:

```
<action>

some action

another action

another action again

</action>

<action>

some action 2

another action 2

</action>

<action>

...

</action>
```

The `<action>` followed by `</action>` should be removed (empty line is also ok) so output should be:

```
<action>
some action
another action
another action again

    some action 2
    another action 2

</action>
```

I'm not experienced in either python and regex and the similar questions + answers seem like chinese for me

Thanks

Comment: I am afraid this question seems like chinese to me

Comment: Please reformulate your qestion, It is extremely hard to understand what you wish to accomplish...

Comment: You should prob at least make an attempt. Break the task into pieces and write a function for each piece, and if you can't figure out some parts, comment it. Give us something to work with!

Answer (score 0):

sed is a nice tool for this

```
sed -i 's^</action>^^g' XML_*.xml
```

this will replace `</action>` from all the files that match `XML_*.xml` regex in your workdir

where:

```
s = change
^ = separator
</action> = is the matching string
^^ = is a blank. if we want to replace a string with string it would be 's^</action>^newstring_here^g'
g = match multiple occasions
```

Answer (score -1):

Split your solution in multiple steps:

1. Load each file seperately (for instance in a loop), you can use `glob` for this
2. Process a single file

The processing of a single file can then be split up in multiple steps as well:

1. Apply the regex filtering (look for a tutorial for this).
2. Overwrite the old file with your new result.